# How to convert case when condition 6 digit decimal to date format (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, format

Would like to convert

```
Case when ItemAltCd LIKE '%WEBLIVE%'
       then Right(ItemAltCd , Charindex('-',ItemAltCd) -2)
     when ItemAltCd LIKE '%WEBREC%'
       then Right(ItemAltCd , Charindex('-',ItemAltCd) -1)
     else ' '
end as 'Event Date'
```

Event Date Output like 123120 (MMDDYY)

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result. (As formatted text, not images or links.)

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms you're using. Several product specific functions are used.

Comment: value is 'WEBREC-123120' in this value in split number like '123120' and after number convert into date format and last where condition applies in a query that results displayed "event date >=120119".

Comment: As @jarlh said, you'll need to tell what **RDBMS** you are using by adding a Tag to your question, like for example `[postgresql]` or `[sql-server]`